# Spring Cloud feign disable @RequestParam validation

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to communicate from `server1` to `server2` using feign.

**server1 - feignRemote interface:**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/validateNode")
boolean validateNode(Detail det, Node node);
```

**server2 - controller:**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/validateNode")
public boolean validateNode(Detail det, Node node) {
    return dao.validate(det, node);
}
```

I'm maintaining a custom `RequestInterceptor` to handle the request parameters `det` & `node`.

But on maintaining the feignRemote interface like above I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters` exception. Here's the stack -

```
at feign.Util.checkState(Util.java:129) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:?]
    at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:127) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringMvcContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(SpringMvcContract.java:194) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:62) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:?]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$ParseHandlersByName.apply(ReflectiveFeign.java:151) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:?]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign.newInstance(ReflectiveFeign.java:49) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:?]
    at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:269) ~[feign-core-10.10.1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.DefaultTargeter.target(DefaultTargeter.java:30) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.loadBalance(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:330) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getTarget(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getObject(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:339) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.lambda$registerFeignClient$0(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:230) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1233) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 20 more
```

But if I annotate the request parameters with `@RequestParam`, then my `RequestInterceptor` implementation wont work properly.

**So is there anyway I can override feigns default configuration so as to disable this `Method has too many Body parameters` validation?**

Comment: Not that I know of. Why the custom interceptor? Are you sharing code between the client and server?

Comment: @spencergibb, apologies for the late response, we had a network blackout. Both `Detail` and `Node` are nested POJOs. So for sharing these between client and server I'm using the custom interceptor

Comment: Are you sharing the interceptor?

Comment: Yes, I have added the interceptor as configuration in both server and client.

Comment: @AJC which SC OpenFeign version are you using?

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek: Its `<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>`.